# How to read a big file in cloud storage with beam TextIO in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a bucket in which I daily insert enormous text files (about 300 millions lines), in GZIP format. Every time a new file is added in this bucket, I need to read every line of it and process it in a Dataflow pipeline. To do this, I implemented a streaming pipeline in Java, with the following piece of code

```
 p.apply("Read new file", TextIO.read()
            .from("gs://my_bucket/*")
            .withCompression(Compression.GZIP)
            .watchForNewFiles(Duration.standardMinutes(1), Watch.Growth.never()))
```

My text files are stored in Google Cloud Storage with the following metadata :

- Content-Type: text/plain
- ContentEncoding: gzip

The problem is the following: when a new document is added, an infinite amount of lines are read from this file by TextIO, as we can see on the following picture (I stopped the process after 500M lines have been sent by TextIO):

[image]

**My questions are: why is this happening ? Where is the mistake in my piece of code ?**

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.7.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Read.html#watchForNewFiles-org.joda.time.Duration-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Watch.Growth.TerminationCondition- says "This works only in runners supporting Experimental.Kind.SPLITTABLE_DO_FN." Have you configured your runner properly?

Comment: According to the capability matrix, it is available in dataflow : https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/. I don't think their is a need to manually « activate » it